# How to set the time zone in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to change the time zone set in my Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu Linux to local time?

**My Question**

How to change the time zone in Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

it should be no different than your desktop Ubuntu process. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Using_the_Command_Line_.28terminal.29)

1. SSH to your EC2 server
2. execute the following (to set timezone to `Australia/Adelaide`)

   ```
   $ echo "Australia/Adelaide" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
   Australia/Adelaide
   $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

   Current default time zone: 'Australia/Adelaide'
   Local time is now:      Sat May  8 21:19:24 CST 2010.
   Universal Time is now:  Sat May  8 11:49:24 UTC 2010.
   ```

**Update**

You can use `tzselect` utility to browse through. See here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tzselect.1.html

It's an interactive software. My Ubuntu (11.10) has it.

You could also refer this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IANA_time_zones)

Brazil

```
Brazil/Acre
Brazil/DeNoronha
Brazil/East
Brazil/West
```

Comment: +1, thanks, How could I set it for different countries, like I have to set time zone fro Norway and then for Brazil.

Comment: I am getting this response `sudo: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found`

Comment: do you not see it in `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure` ?

Comment: No and I cannot do apt-get also. I have posted a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935091/is-my-amazon-ec-2-running-amazon-linux-or-ubuntu

Comment: When you provide user data on your EC2 instance this is the best way to change the timezone

Comment: For Ubuntu from the command line, the following link provides the trivial, 1-line command: http://askubuntu.com/a/524362/182454

Comment: Thanks! If the instance is restarted, would this timezone configuration be reset?

Answer (score 82):

Check your current time zone by

```
$ date
```

To change it, run

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This will show list of geographical areas. Select to narrow down available time zones. Next select city/timezone. And you have changed system to new timezone.

Comment: Thank you for this. It was simple, painless, and a lot fewer steps than other people's answers. I tried the steps outlined in Amazon's documentation, but that did not work. This worked like a charm.

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me. Very simple

Comment: Clean! That's how I used to do it in my website with Laravel. Best one

Comment: This one was the easiest one—a unique thumbs-up to you.

Comment: This is the simplest solution, Just do selection without knowing exact timezones.

Answer (score 75):

Another way of changing the time (This was done on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance)

**Remove your localtime file**

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
```

**Change Directory to ZoneInfo**

```
cd /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

This folder contains all of the timezone information. You then just need to softlink to the appropriate zone.

**Create a softlink to /etc/localtime**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GB /etc/localtime
```

That will change your server timezone to GB

Comment: (be sure to restart apache after applying the change)

Answer (score 21):

Information is available in aws [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) for changing the time zone in ec2 machine .Please find below the details :

Changing the Time Zone

Amazon Linux instances are set to the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) time zone by default, but you may wish to change the time on an instance to the local time or to another time zone in your network.

To change the time zone on an instance

1.Identify the time zone to use on the instance. The /usr/share/zoneinfo directory contains a hierarchy of time zone data files. Browse the directory structure at that location to find a file for your time zone.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
Africa      Chile    GB         Indian       Mideast   posixrules  US
America     CST6CDT  GB-Eire    Iran         MST       PRC         UTC
Antarctica  Cuba     GMT        iso3166.tab  MST7MDT   PST8PDT     WET
Arctic      EET      GMT0       Israel       Navajo    right       W-   SU
...
```

Some of the entries at this location are directories (such as America), and these directories contain time zone files for specific cities. Find your city (or a city in your time zone) to use for the instance. In this example, you can use the time zone file for Los Angeles, /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles.

2.Update the /etc/sysconfig/clock file with the new time zone.

a.Open the /etc/sysconfig/clock file with your favorite text editor (such as vim or nano). You need to use sudo with your editor command because /etc/sysconfig/clock is owned by root.

b.Locate the ZONE entry, and change it to the time zone file (omitting the /usr/share/zoneinfo section of the path). For example, to change to the Los Angeles time zone, change the ZONE entry to the following.

```
ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"
```

c.Save the file and exit the text editor.

3.Create a symbolic link between /etc/localtime and your time zone file so that the instance finds the time zone file when it references local time information.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

4.Reboot the system to pick up the new time zone information in all services and applications.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: On my ubuntu 14.04 there's no `/etc/sysconfig` folder

Comment: @Simone : the above suggestions are for Amazon Linux machine .As you are using ubuntu 14.04 - can you check whether this helps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime

Comment: Thanks, I already found useful this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931566/how-to-set-the-time-zone-in-amazon-ec2. However what I don't understand is this, my server time should be set as Etc/UTC or should be set to my local time or based on where my instance is?

Comment: @Simone Normally- it depends on your use case what you want default time in your applications which will be running on this instance when you say get current_timestamp etc. Normally I personally recommend that you should set UTC time zone by default and then should convert it to whatever time zone you require.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work for some reason. /etc/sysconfig/clock does not even exist. Luckily I found another way, but this does not work for all instances, apparently.

Answer (score 14):

**For Red Hat or CentOS:**

Check the time:

`timedatectl status`

List all available timezones:

`timedatectl list-timezones`

Set up your timezone:

`sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris`

Comment: This also worked for my ec2 ubuntu instance. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

None of the above steps worked for me, so thought of writing this new answer here

```
# Delete any existing localtime link
sudo rm /etc/localtime
# Update time clock file with ZONE property
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/clock
#Update the ZONE property to what you want say
ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: only this method worked for me too ..
wasted 2hours of my life T.T

Comment: If you are using `ln -f ...`, then first calling `rm` on its referant is redundant, and vice versa.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR UBUNTU 16.04:**

Do:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

to update your timezone.

To list down all the available timezones you can do:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

Answer (score 9):

from RHEL 7 admin guide

Seems this might be the command on REDHAT7

```
timedatectl set-timezone "Europe/Stockholm"
```

To get all available timezones type:

```
timedatectl list-timezone
```

for more informations use

```
man timedatectrl
```

Answer (score 8):

Locate your timezone in the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

E.g. To change timezone for Toronto `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Toronto`

Symlink your timezone to `/etc/localtime` e.g. for Toronto:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Toronto /etc/localtime
```

Reboot to finish

```
reboot
```

Comment: I think you missed one step - update your system clock so changes are retained on reboot: `sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/clock` and change `ZONE="UTC"` to `ZONE="America/New_York"` or whatever. Leave `UTC=true` alone since Amazon [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) that for the hardware clock.

Answer (score 1):

**Well described in below link**

**https://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line/594186#594186?s=8f7d09598b2246629a70bb1928501f52**

e:g- sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This refers to a linux box (debian in my instance) should be used under your AWS launch configurations "User Data".

If you're planning to set the TIMEZONE on instance boot use below (works like a charm) use you're own Country/City instead of "Australia/Sydney".

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/rm -f /etc/localtime; /bin/ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney /etc/localtime
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new EC2 instance and select "Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)" as Amazon Machine Image (AMI), you can insert these lines in the "User Data" section. Based on which region you are in, change the second line with the timezone that works for you. I am in Central European Time (CET). Bear in mind that this bootstrap code is executed as root and only once when the instance is created.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/CET /etc/localtime
```

If you want to see all the other timezones available, ssh to one instance and run:

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
```