# Is my Amazon EC 2 running Amazon Linux or Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am a little confused here. I created a Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu Linux 64-bit 12.04 LTS, now when I SSH into it I get the following

[image]

but on Amazon Management console I get the following

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you try recreating an instance? May be you missed something & selected a wrong instance somehow.

Comment: @shadyabhi That of course will be final resort.

Comment: Can you replicate with another instance? A micro should fall in the free tier, or if you want a larger instance it's going to be a trivial cost for spin-up, check, spin-down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely Amazon Linux (CentOS based), not Ubuntu. Another hint is that the default username in Amazon Linux is usually "ec2-user" while in Ubuntu it is "ubuntu" (at least if you use the default stock AMI). I don't know how it can be different from what you selected when you created it, but I guess it's either a human error or a weird bug.

**Edit**: For the record, the problem was that he was using an old EBS volume (which had Amazon AMI) as root volume.

Comment: Thanks David. How does it happen? I created a Ubuntu image. A Bug in Amazon System.

Comment: Either a bug or a human error I guess. First time I hear about such a problem.

Comment: It was because I was using an old EBS volume (which had Amazon AMI) as root volume. Can you please edit you answer I will accept it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ami-acf6b0fe is indeed an official Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise AMI in Amazon EC2's ap-southeast-1 (Singapore) region.

The welcome message you list is indeed for Amazon Linux.

This means that the EC2 instance listed in your AWS console is *not* the EC2 instance you are connecting to with ssh.

You should double check IP addresses, hostnames, instance ids, AWS accounts, and EC2 regions.