# Yelp Place API returning "Invalid Signature" Error only from Nginx on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, oauth, amazon-ec2, yelp

**Problem**: I am getting an "Invalid Signature" error from Yelp API **only from production (running on nginx server in AWS)** When I run locally on my localhost:3000, there is no signature error, and everything works fine.

I am using the yelp gem in rails. Here's some code in ruby.:

```
$client = Yelp::Client.new({
    consumer_key: $SL_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: $SL_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    token: $SL_TOKEN,
    token_secret: $SL_TOKEN_SECRET
})

begin
    $client.search("Los Angeles")
rescue => error
    puts error.message
    puts error.inspect
end
```

error.message prints out: "Signature was invalid"

error.inspect prints out: < Yelp::Error::InvalidSignature: Signature was invalid >

**Everything works when I run locally on rails' Webrick server** but when I run it in production, I get an "Invalid Signature" error.

Has anyone seen this? I've looked at some relevant posts, but this seems different. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your error message(Invalid Signature).

Comment: @JarachanthanRatnakumar I edited the post above with some print statements and what I get.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably not pertain to most people, but the off chance it could help someone, here it is:

My "time" was effed up on my EC2 instance. So for example, in ruby, Time.now was not printing the actual time. (I think it was off by a few minutes or so).

**Anyway, Yelp API requires a oauth_timestamp when you send a request. Of course, then, my request was timing out b/c the time was off.**

How did I found this error out?

I just pinged the URL on my browser with the oauth, token, oauth_timestamp, etc. (few more) as query params. The browser spits out the error response in JSON, and it was saying that my request was timing out. When you use the ruby Yelp Client and catch the exception in code, it doesn't spit out the error response in terminal, so it's a bit more difficult to locate the exact root of the error.

How I solved it:

I re-calibrated the time in my ec2 instance by following the directions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Problem is solved. Peace.

Comment: I had the same issue today but I was using yelp Python API. Somehow stumbled on your question. Then, I understood the real reason. Changed the time and it worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot!
But I have used the time change as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11931955/815539

Answer (score -1):

`Invalid signature` error in `Yelp API` occurs due to two reasons .
First , Either of your four keys i.e `consumer_key` , `consumer_secret_key` , `Token` & `Token Secret` is invalid . Secondly `Parameters` passed to `Yelp API` Function are either invalid or any of those are nil .