# Changing Timezone in EC2 Linux Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to change the ec2 instance timezone to IST but following the aws docs isn't helping at all.

```
  ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia
```

```
Aden       Atyrau   Brunei      Damascus   Hebron       Jerusalem  Kolkata       Makassar      Phnom_Penh  Saigon         Tashkent  Ujung_Pandang  Yangon
Almaty     Baghdad  Calcutta    Dhaka      Ho_Chi_Minh  Kabul      Krasnoyarsk   Manila        Pontianak   Sakhalin       Tbilisi   Ulaanbaatar    Yekaterinburg
Amman      Bahrain  Chita       Dili       Hong_Kong    Kamchatka  Kuala_Lumpur  Muscat        Pyongyang   Samarkand      Tehran    Ulan_Bator     Yerevan
Anadyr     Baku     Choibalsan  Dubai      Hovd         Karachi    Kuching       Nicosia       Qatar       Seoul          Tel_Aviv  Urumqi
Aqtau      Bangkok  Chongqing   Dushanbe   Irkutsk      Kashgar    Kuwait        Novokuznetsk  Qostanay    Shanghai       Thimbu    Ust-Nera
Aqtobe     Barnaul  Chungking   Famagusta  Istanbul     Kathmandu  Macao         Novosibirsk   Qyzylorda   Singapore      Thimphu   Vientiane
Ashgabat   Beirut   Colombo     Gaza       Jakarta      Katmandu   Macau         Omsk          Rangoon     Srednekolymsk  Tokyo     Vladivostok
Ashkhabad  Bishkek  Dacca       Harbin     Jayapura     Khandyga   Magadan       Oral          Riyadh      Taipei         Tomsk     Yakutsk
```

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/clock
```

```
ZONE="Asia/Calcutta"
UTC=true
```

I edited the file to the required timezone and linked it to local time

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta /etc/localtime
```

Rebooted the machine and check date only to see the below

```
Mon Sep 16 16:06:13 UTC 2019
```

Did this a few times with also changing the Zone to Kolkata, nothing changes. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931566/how-to-set-the-time-zone-in-amazon-ec2

Comment: Tried all the suggestions given in the answer, nothing works :)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to change EC2 timezone is to run the following command when logged in

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

this will open screen to select geographical areas, use enter to select and further select city and enter.
This will change the timezone for your currently logged in EC2 instance.

Comment: This is not a Debian based system

Answer (score 0):

for instance setting for Europe Amsterdam timezone. (when run as root)

ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam  /etc/localtime

echo -e "ZONE="Europe/Amsterdam"\nUTC=true”>/etc/sysconfig/clock

reboot

this worked for me , but it requires a reboot.